# Catch a specific warning in PHP cli

Tags: warnings, try-catch, php

I made a script in php-cli that incurs in some warnings, i need to catch only one of them and kill the script "die();" only if it comes.

this:

Warning: `fgets()` expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in file.php on line 46

how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script probably looks like:

```
$f = fopen($filename, "r");
while ($line = fgets($f)){
    ...
}
```

Or maybe:

```
$f = fopen($filename, "r");
$line = fgets($f);
```

You can to handle the error between the `fopen()` and the `fgets()` calls, without using `try[}catch(){}`:

```
$f = fopen($filename, "r");
if (!$f){
    die("Error while opening the file.\n");
}
$line = fgets($f);
```